# Does bluecove work with Linux 64 bits?

Tags: java, linux, 64-bit, bluetooth

Trying to run a java test using bluecove, I got:

> Native Library bluecove_x64 not
>   available

Does it work with 64 bits linux?

My class path have:

- bluecove-2.1.0.jar
- bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found, it was needed to install the libbluetooth-dev.